# PHP unable to access Xpath node of a SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
$x = new DomDocument();
$x->loadXML($responseXml);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($x);
```

Outputting the array using print_r($xml) gives the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Timestamp] => 2014-11-09T18:28:47.843Z
    [Ack] => Success
    [Version] => 897
    [Build] => E897_UNI_API5_17253832_R1
    [Store] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Name] => test
            [SubscriptionLevel] => Basic
            [Description] => Welcome Message.           
        )

)
```

Using $xml->Store->Description outputs "Welcome Message."

When I use xpath to return the Description node using the following code, I get an empty array:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($x);
$result = $xpath->query("/Store/Description");
```

Why does this fail?

Answer (score 0):

Its easier with simple xml.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath('/Store/Description');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Even after I drop the trailing "/" after Description, I still get a blank array.

Comment: Paste the result XML here.

Comment: print_r($xml) outputs: " Array ( ) "

Comment: The XML ;) not the empty result

Answer (score 0):

Simple really, I just needed to register the namespace:

`$xml->registerXPathNamespace('urn', 'ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');`

Comment: That's why you should post the original XML in your question. Not the SimpleXML debug. How should we know about the namespace?